# Trying to search ListView for subitems matching a string

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm having trouble scanning through a ListView to locate a subitem matching a given string. Here's my code:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string date = datePicker.Value.ToShortDateString();
        int count = Program.booker.listView.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = Program.booker.listView.Items[i];

            if (lvi.SubItems.Equals(date))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found!", "Alert");
                Program.booker.listView.MultiSelect = true;
                Program.booker.listView.Items[i].Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing found for " + date, "Alert");
            }
        }
    }
```

The ListView is located on the Booker form, and I'm accessing it from the Filter class. I'd like to search the entire ListView for any items matching my date string. Thanks!

Comment: Is this WPF or Winforms?  Also what is wrong with your current code, does it not work, throw errors?

Comment: Winforms. And my code just won't work. It only searches the first column in my ListView, and not the sub items too.

Comment: Shouldn't you loop through your `SubItems` for each item and check all of them?  I'm thinking `lvi.SubItems.Equals(date)` is trying to match a pointer to a collection with a date, which would always be false.  Maybe change `Equals` to `Contains`?

Comment: I'm searching for a string, and ``Contains`` takes in a ``SubItem`` as a parameter.

Comment: Have you tried changing your condition to `lvi.SubItems.Any(item => item.Equals(date))`? After all, you're asking if *any* of the sub-items are equal to the date, not if the sub-items (as a collection) is equal to the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [FindItemWithText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3h4x385.aspx) method.

```
ListViewItem searchItem = null;
int index = 0;
do
{
    if (index < Program.booker.listView.Items.Count)
    {
        //true = search subitems
        //last false param = no partial matches (remove if you want partial matches)
        searchItem = Program.booker.listView.FindItemWithText(date, true, index, false);
        if (searchItem != null)
        {
            index = searchItem.Index + 1;

             //rest of code
        }
    }
    else
        searchItem =null;

} while (searchItem != null);
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for. But how come only one row is selected when I have 2 date matches?

Comment: The `FindItemWithText` method will only get the first result. What you can do is [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxdakxef.aspx) in a loop, updating the `startIndex` after one is found. I've updated the answer but the code is untested (typed directly into SO) but hopefully should give you an idea though.

Comment: The edited code put me into an infinite loop. I think it's because ``searchitem`` becomes not null as soon as it finds the first instance of its find.

Comment: @RyanCohen - Try setting it to `index + 1`.

Comment: I get an error, ``Value of '2' is not valid for 'startIndex'``

Comment: You don't have that many items in the listview. See the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, multitasking atm :) Try adding a -1 to the `Count` property (see answer) as indexes are 0 based.

Comment: That's because the first run is 0, so `Count -1` makes it -1 which is invalid. See new update (again! lol)

Comment: Sorry, I might have to try it out at a later time. Could you unmark this as an answer and I'll see if I can test it in an IDE later on.

Comment: I did a quick test and my new answer seemed to work. I hadn't realise the `subitems` property doesn't return `ListViewItem` so I was trying to account for that too.