# Searching for subitems in listview

Tags: c#

I know there's already a question here about searching for subitems in listview but it's a bit complicated for a newbie like me. I did a simple windows form application with listview in it and inside the listview there are 2 columns named: 'Name' and 'Age'. I manage to search for the subitems but it searches first for the item in the first column, then the subitem. Here's the code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i <=listView1.Items.Count-1; i++) 
        {
            foreach(ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem in listView1.Items[i].SubItems)
            {
                if (subitem.Text.Equals(txtSearch.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Subitem found!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Subitem not found!");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

(Assume the name: 'John' and age:'17' in the listview)

Input:

> txtSearch: 17

Output:

> Subitem not found! //Because it searches first in the first column(which is John)
>
> Subitem found! //Because it now detected the subitem

If I remove the "MessageBox.Show("Subitem not found!")" and entered a correct input, ofcourse it will show the it has found the item but if I enter an incorrect input it won't do anything.
Any idea how to search for subitems directly? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to search ListView for subitems matching a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974592/trying-to-search-listview-for-subitems-matching-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could approach this, the first (the long hand) is a slight alteration to your current method.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var isResultFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <=listView1.Items.Count-1; i++) 
    {
        foreach(ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem in listView1.Items[i].SubItems)
        {
            if (subitem.Text.Contains(txtSearch.Text))
            {
                isResultFound = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(isResultFound) break;
    }

    if(isItemFound)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Found!");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Not found!");
    }
```

An alternative could be to use Linq to query the items.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var isResultFound =  listView1.Items.Any(i=>
               i.SubItems.Any(si=>
                   si.Text.Contains(txtSearch.Text)));

    if(isItemFound)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Found!");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Not found!");
    }
```

This new Linq Expression is actually doing the same thing as the for loops, just in a more concise way.

Both of these examples will stop iterating around the loop after first occurrence of your search value is found.

I've also used the Contains option instead of Equals to find results where the entry is within the value, for example in a sentence.

---

Edit: Ken's link in his comment is another option available to you.